# how do puffin browser support flash in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios

i know iOS does NOT support flash,anybody knows,how did puffin browser support that.

Comment: Flag for SU. -1 for not a real question

Comment: I do think its an interesting question.

Comment: I think it is an interesting question and would be curious to know how too.

Comment: it is a good question!

Answer (score 4):

Puffin web browser uses their own servers to interpret the web page, and send it down in a format that the device can understand. Their implementation is proprietary, so, unless you can contact one of their employees, I don't think you'll be duplicating it any time soon.